# Requirement of App synchronising Data, Images & Video

Tags: android, web-services, synchronization, offlineapps

Thanks for reading this query.

I have received a requirement of Developing Android Tab & Mobile App for a Restaurant, which should work Offline.

Customer should be able see the list of Menu and details of each Menu Items. It will have Images, Videos, Ingredients for each Menu.

My question is, I would like to develop a Web Services which will take care of Adding new Menu including Images, Videos & other Informations. Restaurant people should be able connect online and  Synchronise the new Menu.  ( If Android is re-started, synchronised data should not be lost.)

- Is this possible to store the new data in the App/Mobile?
- For such App which framework is appropriate?

I hope to receive positive inputs.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For consuming web services you might look into [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
Menu can be saved in the [database](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). It will not be lost after device is restarted.

Each time when user opens the app if the network is available you can perform a check if you have the latest version of menu in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. App will connect (once in a month) online only to download latest Menu, rest of the  time App will be offline. So is it possible to Sync and Store the Images, Videos & Data/Information in App and run it offline till next update?

Comment: Yes, sure, when you do sync you will save your data to the database and app will load data from the database.